# How to add 'state' query parameter to OAuth request (Or ignore it)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, docusignapi

I have created an API Server using ASP.NET Core 2.1. One of the steps involves an OAuth Code Grant with the DocuSign API.

When I go to the Login route, the server authenticates the users perfectly fine, the Auth token exists in the response and the user can do everything they need to.
However, On the users first "Login" (Or if they've cleared the cache), when DocuSign has logged in the user and returns them to the Callback URL, a 500 error is thrown.

Startup.cs

```cs
.AddOAuth("DocuSign", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = Configuration["ApplicationSettings:ConnectionSettings:DocuSign:ClientID"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["ApplicationSettings:ConnectionSettings:DocuSign:SecretKey"];

        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/ds/callback");

        options.AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["ApplicationSettings:ConnectionSettings:DocuSign:AuthorizationEndpoint"];
        options.TokenEndpoint = Configuration["ApplicationSettings:ConnectionSettings:DocuSign:TokenEndpoint"];
        options.UserInformationEndpoint = Configuration["ApplicationSettings:ConnectionSettings:DocuSign:UserInformationEndpoint"];
        options.Scope.Add("signature");

        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ClaimActions.Clear();
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("accounts", "accounts");

        options.ClaimActions.MapCustomJson("account_id", obj => ExtractDefaultAccountValue(obj, "account_id"));
        options.ClaimActions.MapCustomJson("account_name", obj => ExtractDefaultAccountValue(obj, "account_name"));
        options.ClaimActions.MapCustomJson("base_uri", obj => ExtractDefaultAccountValue(obj, "base_uri"));
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("access_token", "access_token");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("refresh_token", "refresh_token");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("expires_in", "expires_in");
        options.Events = new OAuthEvents
        {
            OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
            {


                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                user.Add("access_token", context.AccessToken);
                user.Add("refresh_token", context.RefreshToken);
                user.Add("expires_in", DateTime.Now.Add(context.ExpiresIn.Value).ToString());

                context.RunClaimActions(user);
                context.Response.Redirect("/api/values");
            },
            OnRemoteFailure = context =>
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                Console.WriteLine(context.Failure.ToString());
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
        };
    });
```

The error thrown by OAuth is:

`Error from RemoteAuthentication: The oauth state is missing or invalid..`

Using Fiddler I inspected the request parameters and it seems like OAuth isn't stitching on the "state" parameter.
[image: FiddlerResult]

Is there anyway to add this parameter? Or even a way to just completely ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

state is an optional parameter to pass any sort of additional data that will be later passed back to your app in the redirect uri. Can you try to add the &state= in your request and see if that fixes the issue?